# Issues with catkin_ws/src

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know what is wrong, but everytime I follow a tutorial and have to use the catkin workspace src folder or similar then I get an issue.

I'm in doubt can this issue be solved? what can I do to fix it? Or do I have to reinstall ROS?

Just an example but this is everytime I try with anything:

```
kevin@kevin-Lenovo:~$ cd dev/catkin_ws/src/
bash: cd: dev/catkin_ws/src/: No such file or directory
```

is the issue the location?
/home/kevin/ros/catkin_ws

I use ROS Indigo and Ubuntu 14.04 trusty

I'll be so grateful if someone can help me solve this. I would love to learn ROS. Thanks have a great day to all.

btw I'm trying to run ROS with arduino through ros-serial:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-rosserial-arduino
$ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-rosserial

$ cd dev/catkin_ws/src/
$ git clone https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial.git
$ cd dev/catkin_ws/
$ catkin_make
$ catkin_make install
$ source install/setup.bash
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257455/issues-with-catkin_ws/src/) by [Dynamite](https://answers.ros.org/users/22877/dynamite/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2017-03-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam26](https://answers.ros.org/users/29143/sam26/) on 2017-03-20**:
Maybe you did not overlay the workspace to the working environment(ROS). Have you done that?

**Comment by [Dynamite](https://answers.ros.org/users/22877/dynamite/) on 2017-03-20**:
hey thanks
After reading your comment I went through this tutorial:
http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/workspace_overlaying

- worked out great - no issues.
  then I tried again - same result:

kevin@kevin-Lenovo:~$ cd dev/catkin_ws/
bash: cd: dev/catkin_ws/: No such file or directory
What can it be?

**Comment by [Dynamite](https://answers.ros.org/users/22877/dynamite/) on 2017-03-20**:
btw I'm pretty knew to this only doing basic tutorials and the turtle sim, gazebo so far and two month of ubuntu use. I'm unfortunately kinda clueless now.

**Comment by [sam26](https://answers.ros.org/users/29143/sam26/) on 2017-03-20**:
what do you mean by `then I tried again - same result:` ? what are you exactly doing that is giving out that error?

**Comment by [Dynamite](https://answers.ros.org/users/22877/dynamite/) on 2017-03-20**:
Sorry trying to run ros-serial for ros and arduino.

- I updated the original post for more info.

**Comment by [sam26](https://answers.ros.org/users/29143/sam26/) on 2017-03-20**:
I am quite not sure but if it worked earlier and not working at a later point, the only problem I can think of is the environment setup after ros installation. Check [the environment setup](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu)

**Comment by [sam26](https://answers.ros.org/users/29143/sam26/) on 2017-03-20**:
If you permanently add the sourcing of setup file to the bash script you don't manually have to do it everytime you open a new terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

why you type command like this  `cd dev/catkin_ws/ bash: cd: dev/catkin_ws/:`?

normally, you should type command in terminal like this `cd ~/workspace/src`, because we usually put our workspace under `/home/***` not under `/dev/***` , the /dev index is used to store devices.

---

Originally posted by [DinnerHowe](https://answers.ros.org/users/26306/dinnerhowe/) with karma: 188 on 2017-03-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bogdar_](https://answers.ros.org/users/25988/bogdar_/) on 2017-03-22**:
I agree, I do not understand why you would create the workspace in dev space. To me it looks like the workspace has not been created in the correct folders.